# Getting each line of a .txt and putting it into an ArrayList isn't working

Tags: java, android, xml, arrays, http

I'm quite new to Android and Java programming and really need some help. I tried to create an app which loads a .txt file from a website, puts each line into an array list and then displays the strings as elements of a list. I added a sysout to know if there are as many strings in the array as should be, but it is always zero. I had multiple ideas how to solve this problem, but they aren't working because of errors between static and non-static fields. I can't figure out how to solve this problem, so maybe you can help me.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView listview;
String response_str;
String output_str;
ArrayList<String> releases = new ArrayList<String>();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ABGXThread thread = new ABGXThread();
    thread.start();



    listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, releases);
    listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 

    System.out.println("Anzahl Releases: "+releases.size());
}

public void getReleases(String release) {

    releases.add(release);

}


}
```

**ABGXThread**

```
public class ABGXThread extends Thread{


String response_str;
String output_str;
String[] parts;

public void run() {

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("URL-OF-TXT-HERE");

    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

    try {
        response_str = client.execute(request, responseHandler);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String cut = "nuked)";
    output_str = response_str.substring(response_str.indexOf(cut)+cut.length(), response_str.length());

    parts = output_str.split("\n");




    System.out.println(parts[6260]);
    System.out.println(parts.length);               


}

public String getRels(int counter) {
    return parts[counter];
}


}
```

Comment: Where do you think you are adding strings to a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a call to `getReleases()` in your code, which is why no item is being added to your Array List.

To do so from outside MainActivity class:

```
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
mainActivity.getReleases("Foo");
```

Or if you're calling it from inside MainActivity:

```
getReleases("Foo");
```

Comment: Where would the `getReleases()` call come from and with what argument?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That's up to him, no? He defined `getReleases()` in his `MainActivity` class, and that's the only method that handles adding values to an ArrayList in the codes he provided.

Comment: Thank you. I added a for loop with MainActivity.getReleases(parts[i]) but I get the following error: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getReleases(String) from the type MainActivity"

Comment: @HaoChen That's because `getReleases()` is not a static method. You can simply call `getReleases(parts[i])` (and NOT `MainActivity.getReleases(parts[i])`) from inside your MainActivity class. Please read this article to learn more about Class vs Instance members: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html